# StyleCop for xcode

Tags: xcode, coding-style, static-analysis, stylecop

Does anyone know about some analog of StyleCop for xcode? All my search ended in failure.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org)? It should be included with Xcode as of version 3.2.